# How to output (a json object or a string of this object) from Python to an api url (nodejs)?

Tags: python, node.js, api, command-line-interface, stdout

I have a small python program that generates a class instance with several attributes.

I am new to NodeJS (and ts) and hope I am using the nomenclature correctly in my description here.

I would like to output the class as a JSON (or string of that JSON) from main.py, using the API index.ts file, to a link (currently localhost).

So far I only managed to have the class print in the terminal when I am running the nodejs code, but not in the localhost url (so I am quite sure that the python spawning works correctly).
The URL only shows empty curly brackets {}.

The relevant piece of code in the main.py file looks like this:

```
def toJSON(object):
       return json.dumps(object, default=lambda o: o.__dict__,
                  sort_keys=True, indent=4)    

if __name__ == '__main__':
       ...
       myClassJson = json.loads(toJSON(myClass)
       myClassJsonStr = str(myClassJson)
       sys.stdout.write(buildingJsonStr)
       # # would also work with the following two lines instead of stdout.write()
       # print(buildingJsonStr)
       # sys.stdout.flush()
```

The relevant part in index.ts is:

```
  pyProg.stdout.on("data", (line: any) => {
     // console.log(line);
     // lines.push(line);
     console.log(`stdout: ${line}`)
     // todo: check if the lines that are outputted there are valid json
     //if valid, resolve with the data
     // if(validate(lines)){
     resolve(validOutput);
     // }
   });
```

How can I output the class in the URL instead of the empty curly brackets?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what solved the problem for me was as simple as doing:

```
myClassJson = toJSON(myClass)
print(myClassJSON)
```

and it showed in the API page.